# Android:How to get current location NAME of user in the way a most primitive phone does it? (without internet or gps)

Tags: android, gps, location

There are many questions and answers in stack overflow on how to get the location latitude and longitude without using gps or internet. But I want to get the location's ***name*** (such as city name) in that way. Most primitive non-smart mobile phones (i.e Nokia 1110) show location name on the home screen. Those phones doesn't have internet or gps. So there should be a way to get the location name just by signal tower details, in android too. How to do this?

Comment: "Most primitive non-smart mobile phones (i.e Nokia 1110) show location name on the home screen" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? I do not recall ever having a feature phone, or even a pre-Android smartphone, that showed a location. "So there should be a way to get the location name just by signal tower details, in android too" -- that does not logically follow from your previous assertion. That being said, you're welcome to play with the `CellIdentity*` classes and see if what you want can come from them.

Comment: @CommonsWare The proof is that I own such a phone. :-D And I meant that if such a primitive phone could do that, android too should be able to do that. No complex logic..!

Comment: @CommonsWare OP is referrring here to "Cell Broadcasting", which some mobile providers use to transmit "rough location" (like the city name or district name) via the mobile radio network (uses same technology as SMS). Each cell tower can broadcast a different message.

Comment: @CommonsWare See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_CB_RECEIVED_ACTION

Answer (score 2):

Since API-17, `CellIdentity*` classes were introduced:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityLte.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityWcdma.html

  - 16-bit Location Area Code
  - 3-digit Mobile Country Code
  - 2 or 3-digit Mobile Network Code
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityCdma.html

  - latitude
  - longitude
  - networkId
  - systemId

That is all I can think of. I hope better tools exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I don't see a  method to get the location name by any  of these.

Comment: I don't know how old GSM phones did, but Android does not provide such API. So the answer to your question was *no, you can't* but I wanted to point out what could be the closest to an expected answer.

Answer (score -1):

I can give you a simple soultion when using GPS signal:

Just dondload the file with the most populated 15.000 cities in the world from geonames.org.
Import that into a quad tree spatial index, and search the next city to your place using the quad tree index.

To check if the solution is feasible, you first may leave out the quad tree index, and do a brute force search.

Comment: OP asked for a method that does NOT use GPS or Internet.

Comment: There is probably no good solution for his question. cell Ids to location  data bases are not public

Comment: He is referring to using Cell Broadcast, which some mobile providers use to transmit rough location "names" using the mobile network (like SMS). If there is no answer to his question, then you shouldn't answer the question. You can always add a comment that you don't think there is a suitable answer.